# getting content of <li> when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a list. And am trying to get the context of the list when the user clicks the text using prototype. But this code doesn't not alert the message. What is the wrong with the code?

The code can be seen here:
[www.modernarapca.com/test.php](http://www.modernarapca.com/test.php)

JavaScript:

```
$$('ul#myList2 li').each(function(elmt) { 
    elmt.observe('click', function(ev) {
        var  tab;
        tab = elmt.down('a').readAttribute('href');
        alert("entered");    
    });  
});
```

Markup:

```
<ul id="myList2">
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" class="" >text1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" class="" >text2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="javascript:;" class="" >text3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It should [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Ys9r4/). Are you running the JavaScript after DOM ready?

Comment: the test link is here: http://www.modernarapca.com/test.php

Comment: You are not running the code on DOM ready. When your script runs, the elements do not exist. [Read the docs](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/document/observe/).

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe this one...

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#myList2 li').on('click', function(el) {
        console.log(el.target);
        var cont = $(el.target).html();
        alert(cont);
    });
});
```

Comment: The OP is using PrototypeJS, not jQuery.